# .DWG files to artboards in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, autocad

I have many (100+) .DWG files that have to be edited slightly and exported to .SVG files. Illustrator can do this of course, but I was wondering if I could make one big illustrator file with a lot of artboards, do my adjustments and then export all the artboards to .svg.

TLDR: How can I import multiple .DWG files to multiple artboards in one Illustrator file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to select all your files, covert then combine them into one PDF.

[image]

[image]

Then you can use [this excellent script](http://aiscripts.com/open-multipage-pdf/) to open that combined pdf in Illustrator with each page becoming its own artboard.

NOTE: Illustrator is limited to 100 artboards/file.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Now I have to figure out why the lines get really thin, but this is a great start :)

Answer (score -1):

If the .dwg file is from a 2006 version of autocat, Illustrator can import it. Otherwise, you can first create PDF files and then import them.

Comment: I know importing should be fine, this is more about importing multiple .dwg files into a single illustrator file with multiple artboards :)

Comment: Maybe if you export your file as 2006's versions you can drag and drop them into illustrator.

PDF multi import is already difficult and an "illustrator unknown file" format is even worth i think.

There might be a script doing such work for you that I don't know if it exists.